# Spring Autowired, injecting generic fields in to generic classes, NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, generics

Typing to inject a typed component of a generic interface in to a generic class fails if there are 2 instances differing on type information.

```
@Autowired
BetterObjectPrinter<Integer> integerBetterObjectPrinter;

@Autowired
BetterObjectPrinter<String> stringBetterObjectPrinter;


public interface ObjectPrinter<T> {

    public String print(T obj);
}

@Component
public class IntegerPrinter implements ObjectPrinter<Integer> {

    public String print(Integer obj) {
        return obj.toString();
    }
}

@Component
public class StringPrinter implements ObjectPrinter<String> {

    public String print(String obj) {
        return obj.toString();
    }
}


@Component
public class BetterObjectPrinter<T> {

    @Autowired
    ObjectPrinter<T> objectPrinter;

    public String print(T obj) {
        return objectPrinter.print(obj);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the expected result, is there enough type information available?

The result I get is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'hello.ObjectPrinter<?>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: integerPrinter,stringPrinter
```

However it does work if `ObjectPrinter` is a generic class so the type information must still be available

```
@Component
public class ObjectPrinter<T> {

    public String print(T obj) {
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

All works well if I create the 2 beans using `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations to create the 2 instances of `BetterObjectPrinter`

The above was tested using Spring 4.3.13.

Comment: How can a class extend an interface?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Sorry you are correct, I had edited my code to make the interface a generic class and the wiring does work in this case.  I've edited the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it expected, spring does not know which one of two to auto wire to objectPrinter field. You can use @Qualifier annotation to resolve the conflict.

Comment: This announcement would suggest that it can differentiate
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

I don't believe that in the above example that the @Qualifier annotation can be used because I want 2 instances of the BetterObjectPrinter class, one for each of Integer and String.

Comment: OK, what you expect to be injected here  `@Autowired
    ObjectPrinter<T> objectPrinter;`?

Comment: I was hoping that the type information from the containing generic class ```BetterObjectPrinter``` would be carried forward and the type matching one of IntegerPrinter/StringPrinter will be injected.

Comment: Again it would seem the type information is available because it's being used if we help Spring out by creating the ObjectPrinter  beans via configuration

`@Bean BetterObjectPrinter<Integer> getIntegerObjectPrinter(ObjectPrinter<Integer> op) {
            return new BetterObjectPrinter(op);
        }`
    and
        `@Bean BetterObjectPrinter<String> getStringObjectPrinter(ObjectPrinter<String> op) {
            return new BetterObjectPrinter(op);
        }`

Comment: >>I was hoping that the type information from the containing generic class BetterObjectPrinter would be carried forward and the type matching one of IntegerPrinter/StringPrinter will be injected - The problem is that you have only 1 instance of `BetterObjectPrinter`, which is generic - how Spring should know which  type to use while instantiating it?  Another option you could try is to dynamically register `BeanFactory<BetterObject>` based on available instances of `ObjectPrinter`